# How to Update the contents of DataGridView on timer?

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I am Reading a csv file and then loading the values of that csv into a dataGridview it works but now that I am Trying to update the contents of dataGridview after a set interval , its not updating , reason for updating is because the csv file gets updated with new values from another program , so when the csv file is updated , the datagridview dont update.

Here is my code :

```
namespace ST_4
{
    public partial class Watchlist : Form
    {string fileName;
        string AppDataPath;
        string MQFiles;
        public Watchlist()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Watchlist_Load();
        }

        public void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.Update();
            dataGridView2.Refresh();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        public void Watchlist_Load()
        {
            AppDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            MQFiles = AppDataPath + "\\Files";
            List<ElementsWatch> records;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(MQFiles + "\\Watchlist.csv"))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                records = csv.GetRecords<ElementsWatch>().ToList();
            }
            dataGridView2.DataSource = records;
        }
    }
}
```

I am quite new to C# so I am still trying and testing , but after reading few articles I thought `dataGridView2.Update() & dataGridView2.Refresh()`  Should update the contents of the datagridview ? is that assumption incorrect ?

Comment: Update how ? what is the behaviour you are expecting ? Are you changing the csv file an expecting an update in the UI ?

Comment: Is anything updating the contents of the `DataSource` for the DataGridView? It's not going to change what's shown in the UI if the underlying data has not changed.

Comment: Yes, if that's possible ? I am expecting when there is more data added the csv file then the datagridview should also show this newly added data ?

Comment: @Andrew H  no the source is not being updated , will updating the source reloads the entire dataGridView? Or will it just adds new content if there is any?

Comment: Get rid of that `DoEvents`.  You would have to run `Watchlist_Load();` from that tick event.  If it's a long running procedure, then look at BackgroundWorker or Async-Await to run things in a separate thread.  That being said, do you really need to keep polling the file?

Comment: @LarsTech I tried calling the watchlist_load function on timer event but it's not an ideal solution for my usecase because user can write notes into one column and if I load it again , then those notes gets deleted as well

Comment: `That being said, do you really need to keep polling the file?`

Comment: I do , because there is more data being written to the csv file every 3 seconds, and since I am new to C# I only found this method which is much easier for me to grasp at my current level.

Comment: You have two things competing for your data grid, so there isn't a magical way to do this without getting into complicated synchronizations.  That being said, how is an end user suppose to interact with a grid that has data being written to it every three seconds?  It's not practical.  I would just add a button that reloads the data at the user's request.